# Python - Convert string to filename

Tags: python, file-io

I would like to compose an existing filename in my directory based on a list to eventually open it. I know I have to convert the string to valid filename and I think I do but shows the following error:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'shapes-22-01-2015.log'

Here is the code:

```
for fileDate in sortList:
        logfile = "shapes-" + fileDate + ".log"
        print('Evaluating date ... ' + logfile)                 
        with open('%s' %logfile, 'r') as inF:
```

Comment: Where's your file compared to your python directory? Have you tried either ``logfile = "./shapes-" + fileDate + ".log"`` or using the full path?

Comment: I just try and it works for me. Are you sure you execute your script in the same directory? Try a pwd bash command and use the path in the open function, like this : open('%s/%s' % (path, logfile), 'r').

Comment: You were right, silly mistake, I didn't pass the correct directory. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

1. You can try to open the file, to see if it exists and then continue to the next file:

   ```
   import os
   base_dir = '/path/to/directory'

   for fileDate in sortList:
       try:
           with open(os.path.join(base_dir,
                                  'shapes-{}.log'.format(fileDate)), 'r') as inF:
               # do stuff with the file
       except IOError:
           print('Skipping {} as log file does not exist'.format(fileDate))
   ```
2. You can fetch a list of files that match the pattern directly, and then read those. That way you are guaranteed that the file exists (it may still not open though, if for example another program is reading it).

   ```
   import glob
   pattern = 'shapes-*.log'
   for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(base_dir, pattern)):
       try:
           with open(filename, 'r') as inF:
               # do stuff with the file
       except IOError:
           print('Something went wrong, cannot open {}'.format(filename))
   ```

One thing worth mentioning is that `glob` will return the files in a random order, they will not be sorted. If you want to sort the files by date first and then process them, you'll have to do the sorting manually:

```
import datetime
date_fmt = '%d-%m-%Y'

def get_date(file_name):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(file_name.split('-', 1)[1], date_fmt)

files_by_date = sorted(glob.iglob(os.path.join(base_dir, pattern)),
                       key=get_date)
for filename in files_by_date:
    # rest of the code here
```